# Encapsulation in relation to automatic properties

Tags: c#, methods, properties, encapsulation

Please look at this simple implementation of a customer class:

```
class Customer
{
    public double TotalPurchases { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int CustomerID { get; set; }

    public Customer(double purchases, string name, int ID)
    {
        TotalPurchases = purchases;
        Name = name;
        CustomerID = ID;
    }
}
```

I noticed that there is a get and set option for customer name. Let's say I need to change the customer name.

Is it more acceptable to change the customer name through a method like so:

```
public void changeName(string name)
{
    this.Name = name;
}
Customer cus = new Customer(5,"John",5005);
cus.changeName("Jim");
```

Or is it acceptable to change it by just doing:

```
cus.Name = "Jim";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a method to alter a property is unnecessary. The reason properties exist is to allow you to implement additional logic around the access of a field. In essence, the property creates a private field and automatically generates accessor/mutator methods.

A property like `public string Foo { get; set; }`
is equivalent to

```
private string foo;
public string Foo 
{
    get
    {
        return foo;
    }
    set
    {
        foo = value;
    }
}
```

So, for example, you could implement additional logic:

```
private string foo;
public string Foo 
{
    get
    {
        return foo.Trim();
    }
    set
    {
        if (value == "bar") 
        {
            throw new Exception("validation");
        }
        foo = value;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if setting Name property changes state or do an action which you decided its should not be transparent to users of customer class, use method approach. use property approach for everything else.

Comment: Say that I needed to do something like authorize the name is a real name before setting it I should use the method?

Comment: i would make Name readonly (getter only property) and make a method like public bool SetNameIfAuthorized(string name)

Answer (score 0):

You obviously have a Java background (as I do too :-) ) .  In C# `cus.Name = "Jim" ;` is absolutely valid.  The reason is that what looks as an assignment is really a "setter" function call.  This function can be redefined with whatever code you want, but the syntax to call it will still be `cus.Name = "Jim" ;`.

This is called referential uniformity, and it's a real pitty Java doesn't support it.